# How to test a redirecting function using phpunit if it is getting exited

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, woocommerce, phpunit

I have a function to redirect the user to a particular url which calls wp_redirect() function and then on return forcefully exits the function. I have added the code below

Plugin Function

```php
protected function redirectUser($order)
{
    $redirectUrl = $this->get_return_url($order);

    wp_redirect($redirectUrl);

    exit;
}
```

Test Function I wrote:

```php
public function testRedirectUser()
{
    $order = wc_create_order();

    $url = 'http://www.example.com';

    $this->instance->shouldReceive('get_return_url')
        ->with($order)
        ->andReturn($url);

    $this->instance->redirectUser($order)
        ->assertRedirect();
}
```

Error faced:

```
1) Test_OrderMethods::testRedirectUser
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/xyz_woocommerce/tests/phpunit/includes/bootstrap.php:265)
```